# Fatal error during installation (0x8070643) in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 setup

Tags: sql-server

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuIH1.png)

I can't able to update my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.Can anyone help me, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Seems like the Microsoft Help Viewer 2.3 installation is broken, so cannot be removed. Do you have it listed via Apps and Features? Try repairing its installation, then reboot the computer and try to install SSMS 18 again.

Answer (score 1):

checkout here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/289197/error-(0x80070643)-microsoft-sql-server-management
reboot and try again. also if you have visual studio, close everything together with its plugins